# dsniff & httpsniffing

Tags: linux, security

I run the command `dsniff -i eth0`, and if I open a new terminal window and try my FTP-server, connect, and quit. dsniff returns the username and password.

If I try the same thing with google.com, or other webservices dsniff does not report back the pass and username.

Why is this? Are the sites I'm using immune to this type of attack? I've had no luck with any of the HTTP services. I'm using this is on my localhost,  for testing purposes, no arpspoofing necessary I reckon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using dsniff, you have found out exactly why when developing sites with authentication, it is mandatory to use TLS to encrypt the communications.

The encryption layer does obfuscates the inner workings of the HTTP protocol inside a "protected" tunnel, and `dsniff` is not able to get at the unencrypted stream *in normal conditions*.

For more information, I will leave a link to TLS, and also to an answer of mine in security/stackexchange

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110914/https-is-able-to-prevent-arp-poison-attack-in-lan

from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

> The connection is private because symmetric cryptography is used to
>   encrypt the data transmitted. The keys for this symmetric encryption
>   are generated uniquely for each connection and are based on a secret
>   negotiated at the start of the session (see Handshake Protocol). The
>   server and client negotiate the details of which encryption algorithm
>   and cryptographic keys to use before the first byte of data is
>   transmitted (see Algorithm). The negotiation of a shared secret is
>   both secure (the negotiated secret is unavailable to eavesdroppers and
>   cannot be obtained, even by an attacker who places himself in the
>   middle of the connection) and reliable (no attacker can modify the
>   communications during the negotiation without being detected). The
>   identity of the communicating parties can be authenticated using
>   public key cryptography. This authentication can be made optional, but
>   is generally required for at least one of the parties (typically the
>   server). The connection is reliable because each message transmitted
>   includes a message integrity check using a message authentication code
>   to prevent undetected loss or alteration of the data during
>   transmission.

Comment: Would it be possible to use some tool that changes the port? From 8080 to 80 for example, hence converting https to http? Would that change things around? Thank you for your time

Comment: redirecting ports with iptables wont change the underlying protocol. Read the link with my post in security exchange and as you are new here, do not forget to give points wether people answer your questions, or wether you read answers to others that you like/are useful to you. Cheers!

Comment: Found out that if I use SSLSplit, that changes the playing field a bit. Cheers